# Display count of group by function in same column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying display the date along with count in the same column in SQL query

```
select top 5  COUNT(IssueDate), IssueDate 
from employee (Nolock) 
group by CardIssueDate  ORDER BY COUNT(IssueDate) DESC
```

I need result  as

IssueDate:

```
2015-09-11 (23)
2015-09-29 (89)
2015-08-20 (78)
2016-06-08 (2)
2015-10-29 (234)
```

Any guidance on this how to get it working like above result?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the result you get right now? (Is the problem that the result is in 2 colums and you want it in 1?)

Comment: The result is  fine  i need to format and show data in a single column how can i add bracket ( ? and add the sum of count  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `+` or `Concat` function to concatenate the result

For older versions

```
SELECT TOP 5 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), IssueDate, 20) + ' ('+ Cast(Count(IssueDate) AS VARCHAR(50))+ ')'
FROM   employee (Nolock)
GROUP  BY CardIssueDate
ORDER  BY Count(IssueDate) DESC
```

For new versions(2012+)

```
SELECT TOP 5 Concat(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), IssueDate, 20), ' (', Count(IssueDate), ')')
FROM   employee (Nolock)
GROUP  BY CardIssueDate
ORDER  BY Count(IssueDate) DESC
```